# How to set mr-1 with bootstrap, spacing two jumbotrons without stacking?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have two jumbotrons with `col-md-6` each. They are nicely next to each other. In reality, they are inside modal, but I made fiddle without modal, cause acting of the elements are same. If I add `mr-1` class in left jumbotron it stacks them which is logical, but how to make space so jumbotrons do not touch each other, there should be some margin between them, but I want them to occupy 6 cols each and stack for mobile. I had some light memory particle in my head, that bootstrap used to handle this situation with out stacking?

Here is code:

```
<div class="container col-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="jumbotron col-md-6">
            Some text.
        </div>
        <div class="jumbotron col-md-6">
            Some more text.
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Jumbotrons in Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b63v2ka9/)

Comment: Its not a good idea to mix grid classes with BS component classes .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make the jumbotron in inside your col-md-6 then you can see the spaces around them ;)

```
 <div class="container col-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            Some text.
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            Some text.
        </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b63v2ka9/6/)

Hope this helps.

-Help :)

Comment: Please accept the answer to help others know as well :D